# Reading a file with a few empty values using textscan

Tags: matlab, fopen, delimiter, textscan

I'm trying to read a textfile using `textscan` but I'm having some issues. I found out `textscan` doesn't read empty values, but I can't get it to work.

I've tried using this, and I even replaced \t with 'space' but it's just returning blank arrays and the only working cell is the first (`Data{1,1}`)

```
fid = fopen('20150630_ircs_data.txt');
Data = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s %f %f %s %f %f %f %f %f %s %f %f %f %f %f', 'Delimiter', '\t', 'EmptyValue', 0)
fclose(fid);
```

The problem is in the empty lines of the 5th row:

[image]

File: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5d9600eb0426e3faaadc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you have differents delimiters. 2 "space", 3 "space" ...

So you need to add some delimiters:

```
Data = textscan(fid,'%s %s %s %s %s %f %f %s %f %f %f %f %f %s %f %f %f %f %f', 'Delimiter',delimiter, 'EmptyValue', 0)
```

with

```
delimiter = {'  ','        ','     ','   '};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I had to put a couple more spaces though, it wasn't reading the entire file.